# Where does nix-env query for available packages?

Tags: nix

I know you can query for available packages with:

```
nix-env -qa search_term
```

from [man](https://www.mankier.com/1/nix-env)

I'm curios, how is nix-env doing the search? Is it searching in my /nix/store or will perform some request on the binary cache server https://cache.nixos.org/ ?

It looks like it will work without network connection so I'm curios how does it know about the available packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local copy of [`nixpkgs`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs) (you can use `nix-channel` to manage it), `nix-env` should read from [`pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix).

However you can override that position using `nix-env -I "<nixpkgs_path> ...`